# How to get custom field values from registered user?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

i'm creating a custom field which is used by a registered visitors to put post comments on front-end, and that comments is private to that user only.

i have created the custom field using "Types" wordpress plugin, but i don't know how to show the input field in front end and save the value of that field.

if somebody can point out a tutorial or post to accomplish this is greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom user fields in functions.php

For example:

```
/* Adding Custom Fields To Users */
function add_custom_fields($fields) {

  $fields['custom'] = 'custom Field';
  return $fields;

}

add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'add_custom_fields');
```

You should then be able to retrieve the information using:

```
the_author_meta( 'custom', $user_id );
```